# extracting sentence containing 2 words from a text file in java

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to extract the sentence containing 2 words from a text file. i have used regex as shown in the code below.

```
File doc = new File("D:\\MyFile.txt");

BufferedReader br = null;

System.out.println("enter the regex pattern to be matched");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String regxpat = keyboard.nextLine();


  String line;
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(doc));     
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regxpat, CASE_INSENSITIVE);



  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {

    try
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        m.find();

        System.out.print(m.group().toString());

    }        
    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
    {
    }
    continue;

  }
//i tried regex= "(he)*([.&&[^\.]]*?)Milan(.*?)\."
```

if the text is:

```
"...Thomas Edison is a scientist. He invented bulb. He was born in Milan, Ohio, and grew up in Port Huron, Michigan. He was the seventh and last child of Samuel Ogden Edison, Jr...."
```

- i want the sentence(sentence boundary is full stop followed by space) with the words 'he'and'milan' i.e the 3rd sentnce(the order is not important.any sentence with both the words is needed)
- i tried the regex pattrn above and many others
- but it extracts part of sentence after 'milan' or 2 sentences starting from the first 'he'
- please suggest a method to get this task done using regex or any other method in java

(i am working on extracting relation pattern between 2 entities: in this case the relation pattern is "born in" b/w the entities "edison" and "milan".
i need such sentences as above from numerous related text files or web documents [like biographies on edison or first 500 links from google on "edison milan"] to do futher processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to not expect a regular expression to do all your processing, and process the text one step at a time.

> I want the sentence (sentence boundary is full stop followed by space).

Fine.  Use the String split method to get the sentences.  Use a full stop (period) followed by one or more spaces as the regular expression.  I'll leave the construction of this regular expression up to you.

> With the words 'he' and 'milan'

Fine.  Write a method to input the words and add them to a List<String>.

Write another method to go through the String array you created with another split method, splitting the sentence into words.  Again, I'll leave the construction of this regular expression up to you.

When you find a sentence with the first word, loop through the word List, checking to see if the words in the List are in the sentence split on word boundaries.  If you find all the words, you found a matching sentence.  If you don't find all the words, continue to the next sentence.

Once you've looped through the split String array of sentences, you either have one sentence, more than one sentence, or no sentences that contain your list of words.

Comment: i tried using string split method but here is some problem with the regex pattern i gave or something else.

Comment: `File doc = new File("D:\\aMyFile.txt");BufferedReader br = null;`
    
`String line;`
  
`br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(doc));`
`while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)      
      { 
      for (String retval: line.split("\.\s"))
         System.out.println(retval);
      }`

Comment: sorry for the code format. used back ticks `` but dont know how to use carriage return

Comment: yeah i split the text into sentences, then i used regex. it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify:

- Is your corpus consistent: are **all** "biographies" formatted the same way as per syntax?
- If so, what do you need your pattern to match, or better, what do you need to retrieve from your matches? For instance, do you need a key value pair with "Edison" and "Milan"? Or...?

If your corpus was **not** consistent, then regular expressions would probably not be the way to go. 
If such were the case, you might want to use dictionaries etc. - might be some hard work ahead.

Comment: + yeah d corpus s not consistent. my task s 2 extract relation pattern b/w entities. + ex:for Edison n milan the pateern  could be "born in/place of birth/birthplace,etc". + i am supposed to extract sentences with those 2 words from no. of related documents n use a kind of frequency filter to extract these patterns because these patterns appear frequently. + then i am supposed to use dictionaries also...yeah some hard work ahead:). + as of now i need sentences with 2 given words.

Comment: I see. So, by "I need sentences with 2 given words", you mean you want to check the corpus for sentence 1 containing a name, and following sentence 2 containing a "was born in" expression, and if so, extract the name and location candidate words from the two sentences. Am I interpreting you correctly?

Comment: i want the sentence containing both the words 'edison' and 'milan'. if no match is found, i'll then search for sentence with 'he' and 'milan'. such sentences from no. of related text documents will obviously contain relation patterns like "born in/place of birth/birthplace,etc" which can then be extracted after further processing

Comment: Then I'd go with dictionaries: common city/town names, common or famous surnames, one with "was born in" expressions and one with pronouns for instance. The right combination of expressions would allow you to mine the data you require. I think it would be way out of scope to try and draft any concrete implementation here though. You could start checking out complex parsing/mining tools, such as http://www.antlr.org/ ... Sorry I can't be more specific!